# Show distinct selection in webform?

Tags: asp.net, mysql

If I use a regular distinct selector with MySQL and show the results in a repeater I can show the the data in the webform with the following code.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "posted") %>
```

But If I use this code:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT mid(posted,6,1) ORDER BY posted DESC"
```

I get the following error trying to use the code above.

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a
property with the name 'posted'.
```

So how do I get the data I've collected with the "DISTINCT mid"-selector to appear in the webform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this, [using an alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT mid(posted,6,1) as posted 
FROM Something?
ORDER BY posted DESC
```

Comment: Strange that only gives me the string "System.Byte[]"...

How do I get the actuall value from the field in the databse?

Comment: @theSwede: You'd have to post the code you're running, I don't know what "posted" maps to exactly, there's a layer missing, can you post the code actually running the sql?